# Can one set up a query to count how many times a user has used a word/phrase?

Tags: support

I want to know how many times certain repeating themes are used by users.

Comment: Setting up query may work with SEDE.

Comment: Query is not needed for this. Search is enough.

Comment: Did you search first?

Answer (score 7):

You can simply search in top bar search. If you want more specific search like how many times an specific word is used by specific user then in search bar you can simply write `"desired phrase" user:userId`.

You need to replace "desired phrase" with whatever word or sentence you want to search and "userId" with specific id of the user which you can get by visiting user profile.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Triyugi Narayan Mani in their answer, there is no need of a query of this. It can easily found by search from top bar.

Visit [How do I search](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/searching). There are many search operators with which we can find desired word or a phrase easily.

Anyways, I found a data query with which we can find a word or phrase written by a user in all of their posts. [**Search posts by a user**](https://data.stackexchange.com/hinduism/query/222971/search-posts-by-a-user). Just a note, SEDE updates once in a week.

Comment: I think this also includes tag wiki. Btw, do you know the language used in SEDE?

Comment: I don't know why this downvoted. Didn't I give the right query or what?

Comment: @Pandya What includes tag wiki? I think it's sql.